# reuse shared/bundle between mri ruby and jruby?

Tags: jruby, bundler, jrubyonrails

I'm using capistrano to deploy a rails app, and it uses `bundle install --deployment` to put the gems in shared/bundle. I've put the appropriate `platform :ruby` and `platform :jruby` blocks in my gemfile, my question is if I switch rvm to jruby and then go to my app root directory and do another `bundle install --deployment`, will that mess with any of the existing gems there and replace them with jruby ones? Will I be able to switch back to mri and run the app like I always have? Will both platform's gems be in there, and then what about gems like nokogiri that have java versions, will that overwrite the mri version? Will I be able to just switch rvm versions and run the app via mri or jruby as I please at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out mri gems are installed in shared/bundle/ruby and jruby gems in /shared/bundle/jruby,  so totally safe to switch to jruby, install your gems, and try it out